# How to use setattr if value is not single?

Tags: python, setattr

I want to use setattr to create a plot:

```
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    x = np.random.rand(10)
    y = np.random.rand(10)

    # I want this:
    # plt.scatter(x, y)
    setattr(plt, "scatter", [HOW TO PASS X AND Y])
```

Since value I want to pass is not single, how should I do it? Basically, this should be the result: `plt.scatter(x, y)`

Comment: The operation you want to perform is not an attribute-setting operation. Why are you using `setattr`?

Comment: What does not being single have to do with anything?

Comment: @user2357112 I need to be able to set the plot type dynamically, and I am trying to avoid having a super long if-else code. getattr(plt, 'scatter')(x, y) is the answer that I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is `getattr`. In this case, it will return a `Callable`, so you can just treat it like a function, like this:

```
getattr(plt, 'scatter')(x, y)
```

Is the same as this:

```
plt.scatter(x, y)
```

Using `setattr` in that way would be more akin to `plt.scatter = (x, y)`, which I don't think is what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

You're not setting an attribute, but instead calling one.

```
getattr(plt, some_func)(x, y)
```

will call

```
plt.some_func(x, y)
```

So, in your case, you want to run

```
getattr(plt, 'scatter')(x, y)
```